# Angular 9: NULLINJECTORERROR: NO PROVIDER FOR NGXSMARTMODALSERVICE

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular9

Here I attached my spec files.

actionService.spec.ts

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgxSmartModalService } from 'ngx-smart-modal';
import { ActionService } from './action.service';

describe('ActionService', () => {
    let service: ActionService;

    beforeEach(() => {    
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [NgxSmartModalService]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ActionService);
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

MultiNumberComponent.spec.ts

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActionService } from '../services/action/action.service';
import { MultiNumberComponent } from './multi-number.component';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { HttpTestingController, HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CircleProgressComponent } from './../circle-progress/circle-progress.component';
import { PieChartComponent } from './../pie-chart/pie-chart.component';
    
describe('MultiNumberComponent', () => {
    let component: MultiNumberComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MultiNumberComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [MatDialogModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
        declarations: [ MultiNumberComponent, PieChartComponent, CircleProgressComponent],
        providers: [ ActionService ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents().then( result => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MultiNumberComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    })
    }));
    
    it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
    
});
```

When I do the "npm run test" I'm getting the following error.

1 SPEC, 1 FAILURE, RANDOMIZED WITH SEED 66295SPEC LIST | FAILURES
MULTINUMBERCOMPONENT > SHOULD CREATE
FAILED: UNCAUGHT (IN PROMISE): NULLINJECTORERROR: R3INJECTORERROR(DYNAMICTESTMODULE)[ACTIONSERVICE -> NGXSMARTMODALSERVICE -> NGXSMARTMODALSERVICE]: NULLINJECTORERROR: NO PROVIDER FOR NGXSMARTMODALSERVICE!

can anyone help to fix this error?

Comment: You are writing unit tests right? Why are you providing the actual service in your component test in the first place? You need to mock it and add it in the providers array. `providers: [ { provide: ActionService, useValue: mockActionService  } ]`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `NgxSmartModalModule` in the imports of your spec file like:

```
imports: [MatDialogModule, HttpClientTestingModule, NgxSmartModalModule]
```